# Framework para Arduino

Tags: javascript, arduino

Buenas Colegas,

Tengo una pregunta algo extraña, quiero utilizar un Firmdata para arduino, para ser mas especificos la libreria de Jhonny Five o Cylon JS, pero mi consulta es la siguiente, esos firmdatas funcionan solo si el arduino esta conectado con el equipo o tambien tambien de manera autonoma(osea desconectando el arduino del equipo y colocarle corriente externa)

Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Hola Andrey, ¿Por qué has eliminado tu pregunta y la has vuelto a hacer?  No está claro lo que preguntas. Has de mostrar lo que pretendes, lo que has intentado y lo que te falla o no te funciona. Mira [sk] y [help/on-topic] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Esta pregunta no es relacionada con programación y pienso que debe ser cerrada. Esta preguntando si una tarjeta elecrtonica funciona con corriente alterna, y la respuesta es que no.

Comment: eyllanesc yo NO estoy preguntando si una tarjeta funciona con corriente Alterna, estoy preguntando si al cargar un Firmdata este puede funcionar de manera autonoma como al cargar un programa a mi arduino,

Lo que requiero es realizar un programa con Jhonny five o Cylon JS (Ambos frameworks de javaScript (programacion)) pero quiero saber si con solo cargarlo ya me funciona sin necesidad de estar conectado al equipo

Comment: @AndreyC1995 Hablas de una libreria que es poco conocida sin mostrar un enlace para poder informarnos.

Comment: Este es la libreria de Jhonny Five
http://johnny-five.io/

Y esta es la de Cylon js
https://cylonjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

La librería se llama Firmata y no Firmdata y aquí tienes un artículo donde se explica qué es [Firmata](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Firmata)

Se trata de un protocolo de comunicaciones basado en Midi. Con este protocolo tienes que tener siempre conectado Arduino al otro extremo de la comunicación.

Hablas de Arduino ¿qué modelo de Arduino? Si quieres tenerlo desconectado del ordenador tendrá que tener o WiFi o BLE no queda otra. En el caso de que tengas WiFi mi recomendación es que utilices una plataforma en la nube como [aRest Framework](https://arest.io/) que es de código abierto.

Pero también puedes utilizar otras plataformas como [Firebase](https://programarfacil.com/podcast/medir-consumo-electrico-arduino/) Aún así te dejo un tutorial de [Firmata con Jhonny Five](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/arduino-via-web-con-firmata/).

Si quieres también puedes utilizar una placa compatible con Arduino y con WiFi, muy económica y que está basada en el [ESP8266](https://programarfacil.com/podcast/esp8266-wifi-coste-arduino/), se llama [NodeMCU](https://programarfacil.com/podcast/nodemcu-tutorial-paso-a-paso/).

Posibilidades tienes todas las que quieras lo que tienes que tener claro es qué quieres hacer.

Comment: Exelente Luis, voy a revisarlo a ver como me va.

Actualmente quiero conectar mi Arduino UNO a Firebase, pero el modulo de conexion que tengo es el SIM 808, pero con el lenguaje de Arduino se me ha complicado bastante la conexion, por lo que quieria optar por un Firmata.

Saludos

Comment: Otra opción, por lo poco que se de tu proyecto, es que utilices [Arduino MKRFOX1200](https://programarfacil.com/podcast/sigfox-arduino-mkrfox1200-radiacion-uv/) como alternativa. Esta placa utiliza la red de datos para el IoT [Sigfox](https://www.sigfox.com/)